# Drunk guys in a race, who will win? (random walk)

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, random-walk

We initially have M drunk guys located on the x-axis at positions $\mu_1,...,\,u_M$. As they are all completely "wasted", they will just randomly walk around in this 1D space for a while. After a few minutes, we want to find out which guy is located the furthest to the right on the x-axis.

Let us assume that their final locations are given by a gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu_j,\sigma_j)$, centered around their initial position $\mu_j$ with a standard deviation $\sigma_j$, where $j \in \{1,...,M\}$. What is the probability of the $i^{th}$ being furthest to the right at the end?

**My solution**: Do a very ugly multidimensional integral, which is not numerically solvable, but reducible to a single integral:

$p_i = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma_i\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x_i-\mu_i)}{2\sigma_i^2}} dx_i \Big[ \prod_{k \in \{1,...,i-1,i+1,...,M\}}   \int_{-\infty}^{x_i} \frac{1}{\sigma_k\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x_k-\mu_k)}{2\sigma_k^2}}     \Big]$

As this is really ugly, I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of solving this problem?

PS: for clarification. this integral simply calculates the probability of each value of $x_k$ being smaller than $x_i$. This is why all integrals (except of the $i^{th}$) stop at $x_i$.

Comment: You can make it look slightly more elegant  by writing it as $$p_i = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_i(x) \prod_{j \ne i} F_j(x)\; dx$$ where $f_i$ and $F_j$ are the pdf's and cdf's of these normal distributions, but I don't think you can get a better formula to compute.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, thank you. This is a simpler version of the integral, but still doesn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you are looking at the distribution of the argmax of a set of independent Gaussian. This is a difficult problem and no solution has be found yet.

Nevertheless, these related questions here can give you some partial answers with pointers to the relevant publications :

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/323998
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/295500

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! With "no solution has been found yet" you probably mean that no solution without an integral has been found right?

Comment: Yes, no solution except the expensive computation of the integral you mentionned.

Comment: Thank you! That is a very specific and precise answer, which saves me a lot of time :)